Bottom empty space on CoordinatorLayout android
I'm creating an app where I have to use the bottom navigation with floatingActionButton, which requires to use Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar I have use everything as it requires but I am still getting anyoing white space after my navigation. i am posting this question because I have tried every thing setting android:fitsSystemWindows="true" and android:fitsSystemWindows="false" don't have any impact, giving margin in negative also cutting my menu icon and text.
here is my activity XML code
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomeScreen">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainFrame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
        app:fabCradleMargin="10dp"
        app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:fabCradleVerticalOffset="10dp"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
        app:hideOnScroll="true"
        android:layout_gravity="start|bottom"
        >
        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu"
            app:showText="true"
            android:background="@drawable/transparent_background"
            app:itemIconSize="18dp"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            />
    </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/plus"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomAppBar"/>



</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>



Did you find any solution?
